# PHPexcel multiple users reading and saving to same file

Tags: phpexcel

I'm running into a bit of a problem. I have multiple users reading and writing to the same excel file. When two people read the same file at the same time PHPexcel crashes. When saving sometimes it just doesn't save. Am I going to need to edit the PHPexcel library? I've read about flock for saving. Not sure, am I up a creek? Thanks

Comment: PHPExcel doesn't provide any handling for concurrent writing, nor is it ever intended to.... your code should prevent that from happening

Comment: Thanks, that helps somewhat. I'm still pretty new to programming, so I will see if I can think of something to do to prevent it from happening. Thank you!